# Importing a font to R that isnt in extrafont

Tags: r

simple question, but i cant seem to find a good explanation for it anywhere. I want to use Futura font (which is in the mac Font Book) in R. Futura isn't in extrafont, and I am using a mac (so the windowsFont function doesn't work), I have tried to use the quartzFonts function, but that doesn't seem to work (maybe I am doing it wrong..?) -

any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to find the font files. Some font files on my computer (helvet) are `/path/to/helvet/uhvr8a.pfb` `path/to/helvet/uhvb8a.pfb` `path/to/helvet/uhvb8a.pfb`.

Then you use

```
font.add("name_to_use_in_your_R_script", regular = "path/to/regular/font/file", etc)
```

An example is below. (The font files are downloaded so the example can be made reproducible. For you, you'd change the `file.path("fonts", "uhvr8a.pfb")` lines to the paths to the respective font files.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

<<knitrOpts>>=
library(knitr)
library(sysfonts)
library(showtext)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.showtext = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
library(hutils)
@

A plot using ordinary fonts:

<<ordinary>>=
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0:25 %% 4,
                         y = 27:2 %/% 4,
                         label = LETTERS[1:26])) + 
  geom_text(aes(x, y, label = label), size = 18) + 
  theme_void()
@

<<using_helvet>>=
provide.dir("fonts")
for (face in c("uhvr8a.pfb", "uhvb8a.pfb", "uhvro8a.pfb")) {
  download.file(paste0("https://github.com/grattaninstitute/Assessing-2016-Super-tax-reforms/raw/master/Fonts/helvetic/", face), 
                mode = "wb",
                destfile = file.path("fonts", face))
}

font.add("helvet",
         regular = file.path("fonts", "uhvr8a.pfb"),
         bold = file.path("fonts", "uhvb8a.pfb"),
         italic = file.path("fonts", "uhvro8a.pfb"))
@

<<helvet>>=
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0:25 %% 4,
                         y = 27:2 %/% 4,
                         label = LETTERS[1:26])) + 
  geom_text(aes(x, y, label = label), size = 18, family = "helvet") + 
  theme_void()
@




\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this, I am trying to make it work now. How do you find the location of the font file? I have found the font in 'Font Book' is that what you mean? in which case I'm not sure what the file name is.

Comment: Yeah that's the tricky part. If you can, search for all files containing `futura` in their name. Or look for fonts ending in `pfb`: they might be located in a similar place. It's a problem I can't help much more with I'm sorry.

Comment: Also, I am slightly confused about which bits of the code applies to the font. which libraries apply to the font? And what does this bit do: 

provide.dir("fonts")
for (face in c("uhvr8a.pfb", "uhvb8a.pfb", "uhvro8a.pfb")) {
  download.file(paste0("https://github.com/grattaninstitute/Assessing-2016-Super-tax-reforms/raw/master/Fonts/helvetic/", face), 
                mode = "wb",
                destfile = file.path("fonts", face))

Comment: That bit simply adds a folder called `fonts` and downloads the example fonts into that directory. It's just so you can reproduce it.

Comment: The crucial part is `font.add("my_font", regular = "font-file.pfb", bold = "bold-font-file.pfb") etc`. Most of the other code is just to demonstrate it.